# Select by location from multiple files and extract to shp with ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select-by-attribute

I need to select data by location from multiple files and then to extract to separate shapefiles. I tried to implement this process using ModelBuilder through workspace iterator. However, the tool "select by location" cannot work with this iterator.

Do you have any idea how to do avoiding manually ways (the files are so many to do it manually)?

Comment: Can you add the code you've tried.

Comment: For standalone models or scripts you will need to make the feature classes a feature layer before running select by location on it.  Have you tried using Make Feature Layer on the layer before using the iterator, http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-feature-layer.htm

Comment: To compliment @artwork21 comment look at the syntax section of the help file for [Select Layer by Location](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-location.htm). Note it says the input must be a _FeatureLayer_, you should always look at this section as it explains what the input types of the tool must be.

Comment: @artwork21, I understand it that I have to make the feature class a feature layer, so I did it manually for 2 files just for testing. Now I feed the model with feature layer and use iterator feature. It works but the problem is when saving the feature layer with selected data using the tool "copy feature". It takes so many hours to export a shp.

Comment: @MacroZED, this is the link of my modified model http://imgur.com/a/N6SpK

Comment: "it takes so many hours to export a shp", things to consider and some additional questions.  Where is the model input and output layers sourced (over network or local), network processing usually takes longer?  How big is the selected data to be exported?  Shapefile data if large in size is slow to process against and does not have things like attribute indexes like geodatabase features classes may have to help speed selections.